# Bash script - List hadoop files

Tags: bash, shell, hadoop

at the end of a bash script I have some simple code to list csv files in a certain directory:

```
hdfs dfs -ls $target_dir/*csv
```

But it does not return the list of csv files that I know are there. The only way I can get it to work is by putting that line in another .sh file and running in from within the parent script.
Any ideas why, and a way round it? thanks

Comment: I think you are messing something in your shell script. post your shell file code here. people here will redirect you.

Comment: check $target_dir   value in your script it might be null,  else post your complete script so that we can check.

Comment: Use `set -x` in your script to see what happens.

Comment: $target_dir is not null. When I added 'set -x' it didn't achieve anything except the subsequent code was echoed, with an x in front of it. The code starts correctly with '#!/bin/bash' and then checks for and moves certain files. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Angus that is what `set -x` is supposed to do, the echoed lines should have at least the variables expended. This is good for debugging. As an example if there are local files the `*`-glob expends to you would see something like `+ hdfs dfs -ls /localdir/localcsv1.csv /localdir/localcsv2.csv`. Could you include the relevant line from the `set -x` output in your post. Maybe even both variants (with other .sh file, and without).

Answer (score 0):

I tried running the same script and it worked for me. Try executing your parent script by adding **#!/bin/bash** as your first line in the script. It works if you specifically denote it as a bash script.

Comment: Yes my script starts with that. Then it just checks for and moves files. I tried adding    set -x but that didn't help. it echoed all the subsequent code with x at the front

Comment: Can you please share your complete script. I think its something in the starting lines which is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using set -x told me that my $target_dir variable was empty when I tried to run the line in my question. The problem is having /*csv on the end of it. Everything works fine without that. $target_dir has the correct value in it and lists ALL the files in the directory. I just can't narrow it down to csv ones. In this case, that happens to be fine.